# Calling an API from replying to requestor [Request Tracker]

Tags: perl, api, rt

I was trying to make a custom action where in I have to call a URL and pass parameter upon replying to a ticket from request tracker.

Tried to put this but did not call the URL

```
my $command = "curl -X GET 'http://www.example.com/test.php?m=1&msg=testing+1234'";

my $output = `$command`;
```

Comment: You are not executing the shell command (see: shell_exec).  Alternatively you could use the php curl api or file_get_contents.  The latter being easiest.

Comment: Request Tracker is written in Perl, including actions in scrips, but I see you tagged your question with PHP. Typo?

Comment: sorry forgot to remove i was about to include a question about the php api but already solved it. i will just remove the php from tag. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling out to the shell to run curl, I would recommend using a module like [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent). You can see in the Synopsis the few lines of code to call an external resource. You can `use` modules in a scrip.

Comment: thanks for this. do you have any example? sorry its just that i have no idea :P thanks in advance.